# How to set a PromiscuousMode on Network Adapter using Powershell in WIndows Server?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, windows-server-2016

It's easy to check state of the `PromiscuousMode` for a physical network interface using PowerShell:

`Get-NetAdapter | Select InterfaceDescription, PromiscuousMode`

However how to **set** (*enable/disable*) `PromiscuousMode` on the physical network adapter in PowerShell ?

Network Adapters are based on Intel X722 using latest driver.

Comment: You might try Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty.

Comment: @Davidw it was my first step to check that command out, there is number of settings which can be set but none which in my understanding correspond to `PromisuousMode`. Any idea what the setting name could be ?

Comment: Looks like you need to find the registry key.

Comment: @Davidw Maybe, any idea what key ?

Comment: Look into how to do this with WMI classes. I will bet money that you will have a signficantly easier time getting consistent results with WMI over powershell. While the powershell implementation is coming along quickly and getting quite robust anything to dealing with network adapters seems to be way easier utilizing WMI.

Comment: I did some looking around the registry and couldn't come to any conclusions, so I think Nick W is correct, WMI is probably the best way to go.

Comment: @NickW. any idea what namespace and class would be responsible for that ? I have searched numerous in WMI however cannot find one which includes `PromiscuousMode`

Comment: This might help - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/neteventpacketcapture/add-neteventnetworkadapter?view=win10-ps
AND https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pldmgg/misc-powershell/master/MyScripts/Enable-PromiscuousMode.ps1